# Performing XLookup plus Text Function, and get a type 13 mismatch error?

Tags: excel, vba, text, xlookup

I'm doing an XLOOKUP in my code when a value changes in a particular range (thus the use of target as a variable), but some of the values are numbers stored as text, trying to find numbers stored as numbers. So I'm converting the results with the TEXT function, which typically works fine as a formula, but when using this in VBA, it's failing Error 13 Type Mismatch. Here's the code below.

```
Target.Offset(0, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(WorksheetFunction.Text(Target, enter code here`"General"), WorksheetFunction.Text((Sheets("tblItem").Columns(2)), "General"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Sheets("tblItem").Columns(3), "General"))
```

Comment: Is `Target` formatted as text? Or the range where from you try finding a match?

Comment: Target is Dimmed as a range

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Text` works only for single values.

Comment: Do you use the above code in a sheet `Event`? If so, it is obviously a `Range`, but I and you were talking about that range **format**... So, is `Target` formatted as text, or the range where a match to be found is formatted as text and `Target` is  numeric? I am asking about that because you can use `Text` function only to format the `Target`...

Comment: Yeah, it's part of change event sub, so it's dimmed as "ByVal Target as Range". So try to remove the Text function from the two columns at the end of my XLOOKUP?

Comment: Is it so difficult to answer my question? So, **what format does the `Target` range have**? Is it string or numeric? And probably the range where to match it is viceversa... Isn't it like that? If the `Target` range is a string/text, you can solve the above code line converting only `Target`. If viceversa, it is possible only using Evaluate of the formula you use in a cell... Besides all that, using "General" as `Text` formatting it **does not change enything**.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not trying to avoid your question. I misunderstood it. It's my lack of understanding—thought you were wanting the Dim, which I provided.On this line, it was numeric I believe, and the search range for the XLOOKUP had the value as text. So I removed the Text function code on the two search ranges, leaving it only on the target, and it worked. I'm not familiar with using EVALUATE, so I'm glad I don't have the opposite issue. But I'll eventually have to learn it, I'm sure. Thanks again for your assistance. And apologies for not being better about understanding your questions.

Comment: This means that `Target` is certainly formatted as number, if using it without text conversion did not return anything. In such a case you can use a simpler way: `Target.Offset(0, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(CStr(Target.value), Table_array, 2, FALSE)`... And I did not suggest that you avoided my question. Just wanted to make you be more focused on the question meaning.

Comment: I guess the OP has mixed data in the lookup-column, not only in `target`, and tries to convert the data of that column into text - but that fails as `WorksheetFunction.Text` works only for single values.

Comment: @FunThomas He obviously mixed them, but if converting only `Target` it returns what he wants, this only means that `Target` is formatted as number and `Table_array` as text...

Comment: Oh, I wasn't familiar with the CSTR function. Thanks for that. I'll definitely be able to make use of that in the future.